# How do I escape Ruby string interpolation?

Tags: ruby, string, escaping, interpolation

Given this code:

```
has_many :foos, :finder_sql = <<-SQL
  select * from foos where bars = #{id}
SQL
```

The `#{id}` part is being prematurely interpolated.

How do I escape it?

Comment: yes because ruby interprets as a comment

Comment: @streetparade: Not true. HereDocs do not have comments... in fact, their entire purpoase is so that you can ignore formatting. However, they act like double-quoted strings (So #{code} is executed). mckeed's method tells ruby to treat the HereDoc like a single-quoted string.

Comment: see also http://railsblaster.wordpress.com/2007/08/27/has_many-finder_sql/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put single quotes around the delimiter:

```
has_many :foos, :finder_sql = <<-'SQL'
  select * from foos where bars = #{id}
SQL
```

Comment: Described here - http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/ruby/doc_bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#here_doc